# OOP approach in js with ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, document-ready

...
Hi I have an object:

```
function Page(daoService) {
    this.daoService = daoService;
    this.gamesList = this.daoService.getGamesList();
}

// Rendering thumbs for main page
Page.prototype.renderThumbs = function(idContainer){
    var container = document.getElementById(idContainer);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.gamesList.length; i++) {
        var thumbNode = document.createTextNode("<div class='thumbIcon'></div>");
        thumbNode.style.backgroundImage = Const.PATH_THUMBS + this.gamesList.gameTitleseo;
        container.appendChild(thumbNode);
    }
};
```

and also I have function in my code that uses this object:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (document.readyState == "interactive") { 
        // Initialization of elements
        // Setting global dao service
        var daoService = AjaxService();

        // Initialization for page object
        var page = new Page(daoService);
        page.renderThumbs("homePageContainer");
    } 
}
```

The issue here that when I'm calling page.renderThumbs, field this.gamesList still didn't initialized, because it didn't get ajax response from server. Can you help me to handle with it what I need to change in my approach? Thanks

Comment: you have to call renderthumbs in a callback. i.e.for eg. call the function inside a success call back of ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set `getGamesList` on daoService to handle an asynchronous method.  Here is a rough sketch of what I'm meaning:

```
DaoService.prototype.getGamesList = function(callback) {

    var self = this;

    // Has the gamesList been populated by a previous call to this function?
    if (this.gamesList) {
        // The gamesList property has values, call the callback.
        callback(this.gamesList);
    }
    else {
        // The gamesList was not populated, make the ajax call.
        $.ajax('URL').done(function(data) {
            // Handle data coming back from the server.
            self.gamesList = data;
            callback(this.gamesList);
        });
    }


}
```

You can then consume the getGamesList method call from `renderThumbs` like so:

```
Page.prototype.renderThumbs = function(idContainer){
    var container = document.getElementById(idContainer);

    // The anonymous function will be called whether the list was
    // already populated in daoService or an ajax call is made.
    this.daoService.getGamesList(function(gamesList) {
        for (var i = 0; i < gamesList.length; i++) {
            var thumbNode = document.createTextNode("<div class='thumbIcon'></div>");
            thumbNode.style.backgroundImage = Const.PATH_THUMBS + gamesList[i].gameTitleseo;
            container.appendChild(thumbNode);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: if (this.gamesList) {... what here is "this"? it's not my Page.gamesList isn't it?

Comment: No, that would refer to a gamesList property on the daoService.  If you are not comfortable with it being attached to the daoService and would rather it be on the Page object, you'll need to adjust accordingly to 'cache' the gamesList in `Page`.  Incidentally it appears I incorrectly used `this` in the ajax call, I'll modify the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use promises in your daoService when returning asyn results. jQuery has a nice promise framework
Symbolick code:

```
function DaoService() {
   this.getGamesList = function() {
       return $.Deferred(function(defer) {
            //Do ajax request here and wait for callback/complete
            //replace DoAjax to your ajax or better yet use jQuery ajax that is already promise aware
            DoAjax(function onReady(result) {
                defer.resolve(result.data);    
            });

       }).promise();
   }
}
```

In your page class whenever you need the games list call it as shown below. It will only download data once, every subsequent time it'll use the data already downloaded.

```
Page.prototype.renderThumbs = function(idContainer){
    var container = document.getElementById(idContainer);
    this.daoService.getGamesList().then(function(gamesList) {
       for (var i = 0; i < gamesList.length; i++) {
          var gameListItem = gamesList[i];
          //do your funky html concats or use some templating
       });
    });
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, I have a few questions, may I do it with promisses in native js without other libs? And sence of DaoService: it can be changed, for example, I want to get data not from ajax but from my page (it was loaded before), so will i need to change my Page class? Or I can just override my dao service?